# Matching of two weighted graphs allowing one-to-many mapping

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, heuristics, matching

I am looking for a heuristic for a graph matching problem as follows.

Given two graphs: $A$ (consisting of nodes $a_i$) and $B$ (consisting of nodes $b_i$). Typically the size of $B$ is larger than that of $A$.

Each node and edge in two graphs has weight. The task is to match graph $A$ to graph $B$, *i.e*., find a set of nodes and links in $B$ to map each node and link of $A$, such as the host node/link in $B$ has larger weight than the corresponding node/link of $A$.

The following figure illustrates two possible cases (or solution) of mapping (matching):

- **Case 1**: One-to-one mapping: Each node or edge of $A$ needs only one node or link of $B$ to map. Here the nodes $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are mapped on to $b_1, b_2, b_3$, and the edges $a_1a_2, a_2a_3$ are mapped onto $b_1b_2$ and $b_2b_3$ respectively.

  - Constraints are satisfied: For nodes: $b_1 > a_1$, $b_2 > a_2$, $b_3 > a_3$. For edges: $b_1b_2 > a_1a_2$ and $b_2b_3 > a_2a_3$.
- **Case 2**: One-to-many mapping: One needs more than 1 node/edge of $B$ to host a node/edge of $A$. In the example, $a_1$ is mapped on to $b_1$ and $b_4$, $a_2, a_3$ are mapped onto $b_2, b_3$. For the edges: $a_1a_2$ is mapped onto $b_1b_2$ and $b_4b_2$, and $a_2a_3$ is mapped onto $b_2b_3$.

  - Constraints are satisfied: For nodes: $b_1 + b_4 = 11 > a_1$, $b_2 > a_2$, $b_3 > a_3$. For edges: $b_1b_2 + b_4b_2 = 8 > a_1a_2$ and $b_2b_3 > a_2a_3$.

Heuristics for Case 1 have been well studied, *e.g*., using *eigendecomposition* to solve the *Weighted Graph Matching Problem* ([WGMP](http://www.indiana.edu/~pcl/rgoldsto/papers/weighted%20graph%20match2.pdf)). Nevertheless, I could not find an appropriate algorithm to find a solution as in Case 2. Any suggestions?

[image: Example figure]

Comment: The constraints aren't clear yet -- for case 1, is it that every vertex $a_i$ maps to some *distinct* vertex $f(a_i) \in V(B)$ such that for every $i$, $w(f(a_i)) \ge w(a_i)$ and for every edge $a_ia_j \in E(A)$, $w(f(a_i)f(a_j)) \ge w(a_ia_j)$, and these are the only constraints?  Because this is NP-hard when all weights in $A$ and $B$ are 1, as it's the Subgraph Isomorphism problem.

Comment: With your example for case 2, did you mean to write that $a_1$ maps to $b_1$ and $b_4$?  Otherwise I don't understand why you talk about $b_1b_2$ and $b_4b_2$ being the edges corresponding to $a_1a_2$.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You were right. In Case 2, $a_1$ is mapped onto $b_1$ and $b_4$. For both Case 1 and Case 2 the problem can be formulated as a Mixed Integer Linear Programming, but I am looking for an efficient near-optimal algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: Also, I've just edited the question to explain the solution in two cases.

Comment: Thanks for updating, and the example helps, but the constraints are still not clear.  For example, in my proposed formulation, there is nothing preventing additional edges and/or vertices existing in $B$ that do not correspond to edges or vertices in $A$ -- is that what you intended?  For example, if there was an edge $b_1b_3$ in your Case 1 example, would the shaded subgraph still be a valid solution?  And must vertices in $A$ map to *distinct* vertices in $B$?

Comment: I've read p. 1 of the linked WGMP paper, and the problem they describe there is related but different to the one you seem to be describing (and which I tried to make more precise): In the paper, only edges have weights, not vertices, and the requirement is for the entire graph $B$ (rather than a subgraph of it) to be isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank for the response. The mapping constraints are as follows.
(*i*) If you map nodes $a_1$ and $a_2$ of graph $A$ onto respectively $b_1$ and $b_2$ of graph $B$, then the corresponding edge $a_1a_2$ must be also mapped onto the edge $b_1b_1$ of $B$.
(*j*) In an one-to-many mapping: If you map $a_1$ to multiple nodes of $B$, say $b_1$ and $b_4$ (as in the figure), and map $a_2$ to $b_2$, then the corresponding edges $a_1a_2$ must be mapped onto two edges: $b_1b_2$ and $b_4b_2$. 

These above constraints ensures the continuity of the flow (*i.e.,* flow conservation).

Comment: You are also right about the WGMP paper. For the matching of a weighted graph you can take a look at this one: [A scalable algorithm for the placement of service
function chains](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01355234/document).

Comment: Please answer my question about whether an additional edge $b_1b_3$ being present in the Case 1 example would invalidate the shaded subgraph as a solution.

Comment: For the mapping to *distinct* vertices question: Not necessary. A node in $A$ can be mapped to multiple nodes in $B$, and vice versa: multiple nodes in $A$ can be mapped to one node in $B$. But there must be an internal link (loopback) of the mapped node $B$ (*i.e.,* edge $b_ib_i$) to host the links between the nodes of $A$. I neglected this scenario in the problem statement for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: For the question about the additional edge $b_1b_3$: No, it does not affect the solution. The shaded subgraph solution is still validated.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things clearer.  If several nodes in $A$ map to the same node in $B$, is it required that the sum of those $A$-nodes is at most the weight of the $B$-node?

Comment: Yes. Imagine graph $B$ is the host for each node and edge of $A$. Once you use a node $b_i$ to host (map) the node $a_i$, the capacity (weight) of $b_i$ must be adequate to the demand (weight) of $a_i$. Similarly for the edges.

Comment: OK, I'm afraid this is Bad News: That means that, if every node in $A$ and $B$ happen to have weight 1, then *in effect* each $A$-node must map to a distinct $B$-node (since mapping 2 or more $A$-nodes to the same $B$ node would exceed its capacity of 1).  That, plus the fact that we don't care about extra edges and vertices in $B$, means that we can indeed encode an instance of the Subgraph Isomorphism problem as an instance of your problem, just by setting the weight on each edge and vertex in both graphs to 1.  This is Bad News because the Maximum Clique problem is a special case ...

Comment: ... of Subgraph Isomorphism, and Maximum Clique is an extremely stubborn problem: there are no good ways to approximate it, unless P=NP (considered very unlikely).  This means your problem is not just NP-hard but also hard to approximate.  (Basically: If a fast way to get a provably good approximate answer to your problem did in fact exist, then you could also use it to approximately solve Maximum Clique, and this would prove P=NP.  This could theoretically happen, but it would be the most surprising thing to ever happen in CS.)

Comment: All of which means: Just keep doing what you're doing (e.g. MILP), there is no magic bullet out there.  You could try heuristics based on local search, simulated annealing or genetic algorithms -- hopefully they might work alright on your particular instances, but you get no general guarantees with those.

Comment: Thank for the useful comments. I did actually formulate the problem as an MILP and tested it with CPLEX. Nevertheless it becomes intractable when having a huge graph (*e.g*., a network with thousands of nodes). That's why I posed this question in looking for an efficient near-optimal algorithm. Genetic and shortest path-based methods have been studied around, and I hope to find something from graph theory.

Comment: You're welcome.  I thought of another NP-hard special case of your problem: Suppose $A$ consists of $n$ nodes, all having various weights, but no edges.  Let $t$ be their total weight.  Let $B$ consist of 2 nodes, each having weight $t/2$.  This corresponds to the Partition Problem: A solution exists if and only if there is a way to divide the $A$-nodes into 2 sets, each having equal sum, namely $t/2$.

Comment: I'm thinking about the term "graph rewriting". Is there any way to reconfigure the graph $B$ to match $A$? That is, we do aggregate some of nodes and edges in $B$, *e.g.*, $b_1$ and $b_4$ is aggregated to a single node $b_1$ with weight $11$ (sum of the old $b_1$ and $b_4$), and the new edge $b_1b_2$ has weight of $8$. Of course now we have an internal edge $b_1b_1$ of weight $3$ (correspond to the old edge $b_1b_4$). Does such a *graph transform* method exist?

Comment: Trung and @j_random_hacker, there is a lot of back-and-forth in the comments here and I cannot completely follow which parts have been clarified in the question and which ones not. Can you try editing the question such that all comments are addressed and delete (or flag for deletion) the comments that are obsolete? Thanks.

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me what sort of solution to the problem you want. Yes, you want a heuristic, but what sort of heuristic? I think it would help if you [edit] your question to briefly describe your current MILP approach and why it doesn't satisfy you. (it seems to be the case it isn't fast enough for your dataset, but there may be more issues). It can also help if you can briefly describe describe the actual problem that leads you to look for such a matching. It may be possible that something else is much easier to compute here and would work as well.

Comment: FWIW, I was approaching this from the point of view of "Can I prove this NP-hard, and therefore dismiss the possibility that a really good algorithm for it exists?", and succeeded there.  After that, I didn't really offer any actual heuristics, just mentioned a few general strategies for them.